# How to disable MacBook Air wireless under Windows 7 (like flight mode)?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

My boss has a MacBook Air with Windows 7 installed.

Because he flies a lot, he wants a tool to disable wireless. Is disabling Wi-Fi enough? If not, is there software for Windows 7 to allow this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you disbale the WiFi adapter, that will give you the result you wish

Comment: What about Bluetooth?